# new to Perl - having trouble with a floating point comparison

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl, writing a simple script that checks to see if the installed version of VMware Fusion is greater than 8.4.  I'm getting this error:

```
syntax error at ./test.pl line 8, near ");"
```

This is the script:

```
 @vmVersion = `defaults read /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Info CFBundleShortVersionString`;

 @vmMinimum = 8.4;

if($vmVersion > $vmMinimum);

then print "compliant";

 else print "update required";

 fi
```

Comment: Please you [code blocks to format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to take a wild guess at Perl's syntax and then act surprised when you get a syntax error. This stuff is really simple to look up on the internet.

Comment: `@vmMinimum = 8.4;` is not valid Perl... neither is most of the rest of the code.

Comment: @JimGarrison: `@vmMinimum = 8.4;` is fine.

Comment: @JimGarrison to expand on Borodin's comment, it will assign `8.4` as the first and only item of the array `@vmMinimum`. If there was anything else in that variable (like a longer list) it is now gone. Essentially a single value is a one-item list and the parenthesis `()` are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code you have isn't Perl. Here's what might look more like Perl:

```
my $vmVersion = `defaults read '/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Info' CFBundleShortVersionString`;
if ($vmVersion > 8.4) {
    print "compliant";
} else {
    print "update required";
}
```

Note two things:

1. Version numbers are not floating point numbers. You should really use a semantic version library, such as [SemVer](https://metacpan.org/pod/SemVer), for version comparison.
2. Your messages should probably include newline characters (`\n`). Without those, when a user runs your program, their prompt will print in a funny location afterwards. :-)

Comment: `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`... It would even have found one of the OP's problems.

Comment: The [`version` pragma](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/version/lib/version.pm) that Perl brings should be pretty good at doing that too, if those version numbers are semantically similar to those used in the Perl world.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen

```
if($vmVersion > $vmMinimum);
...
fi
```

In perl before, replace with block braces.

```
if($vmVersion > $vmMinimum) {
...
}
```